# Difficulties removing files from an S3 bucket. How can I use logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parse-server, s3-bucket

Having not yet figured out how to solve the issue mentioned in [StackOverflow: Cannot remove audio data on AWS-S3 in a Parse-Server app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50013876/174777).

I started to tackle the problem by setting access logs on the server, following [Amazon S3 Server Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html), and see what is happening.

When I run the code, I now see in the logs that there is a permission issue.

But I do not know what is supposed to have a delete-permission and does not have it.

Any suggestion on that matter, by some experienced person would be very much appreciated.

Just for reference, this is the kind of errors I can see in the logs:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>838B2DE1279DC928</RequestId>
<HostId>Iu0JWlKTOz92+GTmI4fYXgQKa7b+BQppb/vNcjUDpsQDqvd+Our4nS7xNtsawQycTsP2A5F71h8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

This log tells me that there is an "Access Denied", I don't know how to make sense of the rest.

At this point I have tried to add AmazonS3FullAccess to every user or role that I could think of, related to this bucket; and it still does not work. I am definitely missing something. It may be obvious, but I have very little experience with these issues and can't see it.

Comment: Can you include the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: ...and perhaps an example log entry.

Comment: I just edited the post to provide this kind of info. I hope this will be useful.